# Assign a class to multiple elements based on a value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im building a simple function that assigns a class that contains a color based on the element's value. My question is do i have to loop through my elements in order to do this?

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jre09a81/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <ul>
     <li class="MyScore">90</li>
     <li class="MyScore">82</li>
     <li class="MyScore">77</li>
     <li class="MyScore">66</li>
     <li class="MyScore">62</li>
     <li class="MyScore">50</li>
     <li class="MyScore">42</li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .good{
     background-color: green;
  }
   .okay{
       background-color: yellow;
  }
   .bad{
     background-color: red;
  }
```

**JS**

```
 function scoreColor(score){
    var score = document.querySelector('.MyScore').innerHTML;
    var scoreColor = document.querySelector('.MyScore');



    if(score > 85){
        scoreColor.className + ' good';
        console.log('good');

    } else if(score > 65 && score < 85 ){
        scoreColor.className + ' okay';
        console.log('okay');
    } else {
        scoreColor.className + ' bad';
        console.log('bad');
    }
}
scoreColor();
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes you will need to loop.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and see comments inside ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/jre09a81/2/)):

```
 function scoreColor() {
     var scores = document.querySelectorAll('.MyScore'); // get all elements with .Myscore

     Array.prototype.forEach.call(scores, function (item) { // iterate the elements

         var score = parseInt(item.innerText, 10); // get the value from the text and parse it

         if (score > 85) {
             item.classList.add('good'); // add good to the item classList
             console.log('good');

         } else if (score > 65 && score < 85) {
             item.classList.add('okey'); // add okey to the item classList
             console.log('okay');
         } else {
             item.classList.add('bad'); // add bad to the item classList
             console.log('bad');
         }
     });


 }
 scoreColor();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to elaborate on this such as `var score = Math.Floor(parseInt(item.innerText, 10));` Basically remove decimal points. I cant seem to get that to work.

Comment: parseInt returns integers. If you need decimals, use parseFloat instead. Why do you floor integers anyway?

Comment: well my actual values have decimal points. I've used math.floor to remove decimals before and worked fine. your code works with my decimal values as well.

Comment: So just use parseInt if you want just the integer.

Comment: My values are coming from a backend for example "76.2". I want to round these off for visual purposes and also use these values to assign a class. ParseInt and ParseFloat both seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
for (let x of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.MyScore'))) {
    let score = parseInt(x.innerHTML);
    if (score > 85){
        x.className = 'good';
    } else if (score > 65 && score < 85){
        x.className = 'okay';
    } else {
        x.className = 'bad';
    }
}
```

`querySelectorAll` returns an iterator for all matching elements (`Array.from` just turns this into an array).